# altering the data type of a column

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, user-defined-types

In the previous part of this problem I had to create a PHONE_LIST_TYPE varray(3).

A. Define a user-defined object type data type named phone_typewith attributes COUNTRY_CODE, AREA_CODE and PHONE_NUMBER.

B.Define a user-defined VARRAY data type named Phone_List_type as an array of size three of the type phone_type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE phone_list_type AS VARRAY(3) of PHONE_TYPE
```

c.Modify the table STUDENT1 such that the attribute PHONE is of data type Phone_List_type.

```
ALTER TABLE student1
ALTER COLUMN phone phone_list_type not null;
```

There is a syntax error line under the alter column portion and I cant figure out how to resolve this error.

Comment: Depending on your database (Oracle, MySql, Postgre etc) you need to use `ALTER TABLE name ALTER COLUMN ....` or `ALTER TABLE name MODIFY COLUMN ....` or `ALTER TABLE name MODIFY ...` syntax, because each database uses a little different syntax - see this link for details: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp

Answer (score 2):

Presuming previously you have :

```
CREATE TYPE PHONE_TYPE AS OBJECT ( COUNTRY_CODE int, 
                                   AREA_CODE    int,
                                   PHONE_NUMBER varchar2(15) );

CREATE TABLE student1( id int, phone varchar2(15) );
```

To be able change the data type you normally need the syntax :

```
ALTER TABLE student1
MODIFY ( phone phone_type );
```

But in this case you'd get **ORA-22858 : invalid alteration of datatype** error. Because it's not possible to convert a column with basic type(string,numeric...) to a composite one in a classical manner like the way among them (*by the way, also in that case, the column which's data type will be converted should be empty*).

So, add a new column with a temporary name :

```
ALTER TABLE student1 ADD (phone2 phone_type);
```

And, populate the `phone_number` component of that new column with the existing data :

```
UPDATE student1 s 
   SET s.phone2.phone_number = phone;
```

Lastly, drop and rename with the existing name of the column :

```
ALTER TABLE student1 DROP COLUMN phone;
ALTER TABLE student1 RENAME COLUMN phone2 TO phone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what database are you using. Here are the mst common ones:

SQL Server / MS Access:

```
ALTER TABLE student1
ALTER COLUMN phone phone_list_type NOT NULL;
```

My SQL / Oracle(before v. 10G):

```
ALTER TABLE student1
MODIFY COLUMN phone phone_list_type NOT NULL;
```

Oracle 10G and later:

```
ALTER TABLE student1
MODIFY phone phone_list_type NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I have tried the all three ways.  If I use the SQL server method then there is a red line under the alter in alter column.  If I use the MY SQL method then there is an error line under phone_list_type.  The error that is recorded is: "Check compiler log"

Comment: you still haven't revealed which database are you using

Comment: oracle SQL developer

Comment: how did you created the type "phone_list_type" ?? can you edit the question and add it there?